# URL Encode for HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android

I wrote a code to get values from API call... it is working fine with normal URLs but when I encode the URL and then make the call means it is not working... it is giving status error 404

```
URL url = new URL(params[0]);
URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
url = uri.toURL();
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

Origianl URL

```
https://staging.xyz.com/odata/Venues?$expand=Fixtures($filter=day(DateTime) eq 1 and month(DateTime) eq 12 and year(DateTime) eq 2018)&$filter=Fixtures/any(f: day(f/DateTime) eq 1 and month(f/DateTime) eq 12 and year(f/DateTime) eq 2018)
```

Encoded URL

```
http://staging.xyz.com/odata/Venues?$expand=Fixtures($filter=day(DateTime)%20eq%201%20and%20month(DateTime)%20eq%2012%20and%20year(DateTime)%20eq%202018)&$filter=Fixtures/any(f:%20day(f/DateTime)%20eq%201%20and%20month(f/DateTime)%20eq%2012%20and%20year(f/DateTime)%20eq%202018)
```

Is there way to make the encoded URL to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can encode your String URL individual queries (seperated by '&') with `URLEncoder.encode(YOUR_URL)` then combine them together in the end.

Alternatively, you can use `Uri.parse` to encode the entire URL if you have the keys and values of your query parameters available separately like this:

```
String uri = Uri.parse("http://...") //the "root" url without any query parameters
                .buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter("key", "val")
                .build().toString();
```

Comment: Please note that you only put in the query through `encode`. Do not pass the protocol and hostname through that method.

Comment: This is the actual URL https://staging.xyz.com/odata/Venues?$expand=Fixtures($filter=day(DateTime) eq 1 and month(DateTime) eq 12 and year(DateTime) eq 2018)&$filter=Fixtures/any(f: day(f/DateTime) eq 1 and month(f/DateTime) eq 12 and year(f/DateTime) eq 2018)

When we encode it as you say, it will encode everything including HTTP also it won't work.

Comment: JensV is right, you can't pass in the `https://` part in as well, but I suppose it will be quite easy to just encode the rest of it and combine the entire url later.

Comment: When I use this method for encoded URL 

URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
            url = uri.toURL();

convert the url to string and copypaste that url to browser means it is working fine.

But when we use only URLEncoder.encode("$expand=Fixtures($filter=day(DateTime) eq 1 and month(DateTime) eq 12 and year(DateTime) eq 2018)&$filter=Fixtures/any(f: day(f/DateTime) eq 1 and month(f/DateTime) eq 12 and year(f/DateTime) eq 2018)");

Not working

Comment: How is it not working? What kind of result are you getting?

Comment: Same status 404

Comment: Looks like you have multiple query parameters, I have updated the answer, you need to encode them separately and combine them together in the end. Otherwise the & that combines the queries will be changed

Comment: I'm talking about the result URL you are getting, what does it look like

Comment: Thanks jackz I solved the problem like this, replaced the space with %20

String BASE_URL2 = stagingUrl1 + "odata/Venues?$expand=Fixtures($filter=day(DateTime) eq 1 and month(DateTime) eq 12 and year(DateTime) eq 2018)&$filter=Fixtures/any(f: day(f/DateTime) eq 1 and month(f/DateTime) eq 12 and year(f/DateTime) eq 2018)";
            BASE_URL2 = BASE_URL2.replaceAll("\\s", "%20");

Comment: You don't have to do this yourself since it could lead to problems, but if it works I guess it's fine for now. If you have the individual queries separately available, then just use my method, it'll be easier and safer.

Answer (score 0):

A URL is very restricted regarding the characters it might include. The only safe characters are:

- A–Z
- a–z
- 0–9
- _ . ~

Other characters can be included if they are encoded, e.g. `(` can be included if it is encoded as `%28`.

Certain characters must be encoded depending on the purpose, in particular `?`, `&` and `=`. The must NOT be encoded if they are used to provide the query parameters; the must be encoded if they are part of the query value.

So encoding must happend before you construct the query part:

- Encode each query value separately using `URLEncoder.encode(queryValue)`.
- Then concatenate the query part: `query = "expand=" + encodedExpandValue + "&filter=" + encodedFilterValue`.
- Then create the entire URL.

And the `/` character is very problematic, no matter if it appears encoded or not. Some web servers will always treat it as a path separator. It better to avoid it in the query part.

Comment: I solved the problem like this, replaced empty space with %20 I did not encode the URL

String BASE_URL2 = stagingUrl1 + "odata/Venues?$expand=Fixtures($filter=day(DateTime) eq 1 and month(DateTime) eq 12 and year(DateTime) eq 2018)&$filter=Fixtures/any(f: day(f/DateTime) eq 1 and month(f/DateTime) eq 12 and year(f/DateTime) eq 2018)";
            BASE_URL2 = BASE_URL2.replaceAll("\\s", "%20");